# Curved lines on a paper

Tags: mathematics

There are curved lines drawn on a piece of paper. Lines can have two characteristics:

1. One of its endpoints is on another characteristic 1 line
2. One of its endpoints is on another characteristic 2 line, exactly halfway between:

   - Its two endpoints
   - A point where a characteristic 2 line touches it and an endpoint
   - Two points where a characteristic 2 line touches it

Is it possible for there to be a third characteristic such that, for all sets of lines

- It is impossible for all possible characteristic 3 starting points connect to a unique characteristic 1 endpoint
- It is impossible for all possible characteristic 2 starting points connect to a unique characteristic 3 starting point

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding this question. You say that lines can have characteristic 1 or characteristic 2. What is a "characteristic 2 starting point"? Is "characteristic 3" something that lines can have? Can a line have both characteristics 1 and 2? What about 1 and 3, or 2 and 3?

Comment: It may be helpful to replace the "characteristics" with colors (assuming each line gets one characteristic) and drawing an example picture.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, if we define characteristic 3 curves like so:

3. A characteristic 3 curve cannot touch a curve of another characteristic at any point.

This trivially satisfies both criteria.